# Arduino Ramp Mapped Values

Tags: button, dictionary, arduino

I am working on a project where I need to adjust a mapped value based on a switch position, but then I would like to ramp the the new analog data when I write it.

An example,  lets say we want to make a button output different voltage (serial robot controller). From my knowledge it will look something like this:

```
 if( adjenpos == 1) {
boostbtnout = map(boostbtnin, 0, 1023, 0, 51);
}
else if( adjenpos == 2) {
boostbtnout = map(boostbtnin, 0, 1023, 0, 102);
}
else if( adjenpos == 3) {
boostbtnout = map(boostbtnin, 0, 1023, 0, 153);
}
else if( adjenpos == 4) {
boostbtnout = map(boostbtnin, 0, 1023, 0, 204);
}
else if( adjenpos == 5) {
boostbtnout = map(boostbtnin, 0, 1023, 0, 255);
}
```

Now with option 3, taking a button which has an on/off value of 0 or 153, I want to ramp the value 0 to 153 over a prescribed rate, instead of just on or off.

My assumption is to do something similar to this inside the loop:

```
boostramp = 1
boostbtnvalue = analogRead(boostbtnout)
 analogWrite(boostbtn, boostbtnvalue);
 if ( boostpwr <= boostbtnout){
 boostpwr = boostpwr + boostramp;
```

I know this is not correct, but how do I inject the new mapped values into a rampped type of function?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

So, if I am correct you want to increase the voltage with each switch position, but ramp it up slowly so your device doesn't go flying to it.  assuming that is right, you want something like this:

First I would make a function to get the positions to a variable (pos), then you can do the rest using that

```
int pos;
int target;
int currentPower = 0;

if(pos == 0){ target = 100
}
else if(pos == 1){target =200
}
else if(pos == 2){ target = 300
}
if(target > currentPower){
while(currentPower < target){
currentPower++;
delay(10); //tweak to change ramp speed
}
}
if(target < currentPower){
while(currentPower > target){
currentPower--;
delay(10);
}
}
```

obviously change the values to whay you need, but that is the idea. first set the positions to 0 through whatever, then determine the target, then a while loop to increase it.